# INNER JOIN MySQL Error: 1054 (Unknown column 'prodotti.id' in 'on clause')

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am getting a SQL error that I don't understand. This is the error I get:

```
Database error: Invalid SQL: 
SELECT distinct prodotti.nome, prodotti.id, prodotti.image_news, 
       imgprod.path, imgprod.alt 
  FROM `prodotti`, `categorie`, `prodcat`, 
       `gruppi` INNER JOIN imgprod ON prodotti.id = imgprod.idprod 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN radiation 
            ON prodotti.radiation_id = radiation.id_radiation 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN installation 
            ON prodotti.installation_id = installation.id_installation 
 WHERE 1=1 and prodotti.id = prodcat.idprod 
   and prodcat.idcat = categorie.id 
   and categorie.idgruppo = gruppi.id 
   and (gruppi.nome like 'ANT%' OR gruppi.nome like 'WIR%') 
   AND radiosystem LIKE '%VHF%' 
 GROUP BY prodotti.id ORDER BY prodotti.nome ASC
```

And this is another error I'm getting:

```
INNER JOIN MySQL Error: 1054 (Unknown column 'prodotti.id' in 'on clause')
```

This works on an old server, but on a new server with php 5.3.16 I am getting these errors. Can you please explain what the error means?

Comment: 1. You're mixing implicit comma-style joins and explicit ANSI-style joins in the same query. 2. You using both DISTINCT and GROUP BY. Rewrite your query using explicit ANSI-style joins

Comment: thank you, but I think I need an example

Answer (score 2):

Your query rewritten using only explicit ANSI-style joins might look like

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.nome, p.image_news, i.path, i.alt 
  FROM prodotti p JOIN prodcat pc
    ON p.id = pc.idprod JOIN categorie c 
    ON pc.idcat = c.id JOIN gruppi g 
    ON c.idgruppo = g.id JOIN imgprod i 
    ON p.id = i.idprod LEFT JOIN radiation r
    ON p.radiation_id = r.id_radiation LEFT JOIN installation n 
    ON p.installation_id = n.id_installation 
 WHERE 1 = 1 
   AND (g.nome LIKE 'ANT%' OR g.nome LIKE 'WIR%') 
   AND radiosystem LIKE '%VHF%' 
 GROUP BY p.id, p.nome, p.image_news, i.path, i.alt
 ORDER BY p.nome
```

*It's impossible to tell more than that not seeing exact table schemas.*